# Remove Action bar Icon with custom view and show home up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am able to add custom view in `actionbar`. My application is supporting from version 2.3 so I had used `ActionbarActivity`. Now my query is to remove app icon from the `actionbar` and only to have home up icon i.e back image.

I had tried lots of option that I found while searching. But its not working with custom view.

## edit

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                    | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.custom_action_view, null); // layout which contains
                                                
    actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
    

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#a40404")));
```

Help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't show up button without home icon.

Comment: @DoctororDrive is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The up button is tied to home icon. That's why it's called "home as up" **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)**.

So you can't show up arrow with disabled "home" icon.

But you can make a View that looks like it in your custom View.

For example:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@android:id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- this will show tha up arrow -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"/>

        <!-- place here any View that will be clickable along with "up" arrow (in this example, it's an icon) -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Where

```
android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
```

Will set the up arrow based on your theme.

```
android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

Will set the blue selection background for pressed state

Now set an OnClickListener to a layout with arrow

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
        R.layout.custom_action_view, null);

customNav.findViewById(android.R.id.home).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // up button clicked
    }
});


actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
```

Answer (score -1):

**To remove Actonbar Icon**:

Just add `actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);` this line in `oncreate()` method:

**To enable back button**:

you need to  extends **SherlockActivity** and insert this code in `oncreate()` method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**Handle back button action using this code:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
              // do your action here when click on back button showing on action bar
                 onBackPressed();
              }
    }
```