# How To Title Aligned at center with action Menu

Tags: android

I am new in android. and I am using an action bar. I have a problem that if I customized the action bar,then text at left hand on `ActionBar` with up icon is not showing . I am attaching a image to clear understanding of my problem.

[image: File]

I Want to Action Bar Like that Image

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.center_action_bar_text);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

center_action_bar_tex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#f00">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="bbj"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what have you tried? show your code. use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true).` with actionbar. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194107/remove-action-bar-icon-with-custom-view-and-show-home-up-button)

Comment: @SweetWisher now I have mention the code when i have implemented

Comment: Post xml and the screenshot of what you are getting right now

Comment: where is *Back* and *Create* ??

Comment: What Back and Create ??